# OAuth 2.0 vs API Keys

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, amazon-cognito

I currently have an application with a React front end and a Node.js backend API that is secured by a JWT implementation for authentication.  We are considering moving to AWS Cognito in order to delegate authentication to a more robust platform.

We also have plans to open our API's to third parties for consuming/creating data within our platform.  Some of these third party clients would be batch/server processes that call our APIs, so forcing a user to login via an Authorization Code flow does not seem suitable.  We would like to issue API keys or credentials via our web portal, much in the same way you would gather credentials for consuming Google Maps API's.

If we were to use the OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant, we don't have a way to identify the user or the company calling the API as I understand it, as it would not have a user to look up the custom attributes needed to call our APIs (company, user).  I also don't believe that Cognito offers a password grant type to fulfill this need, and I understand this is no longer a recommended grant type in OAuth 2.0.

What are the best recommendations for using OAuth for user authentication while also allowing users to generate API keys?  Would a solution include offering different authentication mechanisms depending on the integration type?  Or do I force clients to implement an OAuth Flow for their server processes and retain the refresh token?

I'm trying to envision a solution like Google which offers OAuth authentication for users while allow developers to obtain API keys for back end processes?